# How to change the tab bar item relationship with view controller?

Tags: ios, uistoryboard

I am new to iOS . How to change when embedded tab-bar controller in my three view controller .when I embedded  it is the default relationship with `HistoryViewController` ,but I want 1st tab item will be `RecentNewsViewController` and run time it will be first viewed .

Thanks, if need any information let me know please

Comment: Can you post your storyBoard? So we can understand better..

Comment: @Joe thanks can you give me some hints how can i solve this problem ?

Comment: If you want your 1st VC to be RecentNewsViewController . you can simple drag and move your tabBar icon where ever you want to set in tabBarController.

Comment: @Joe good job ... It should  be an answer :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**Note:** Below answer based on the conversation between the question owner.

If you want your 1st **VC** to be `RecentNewsViewController`.You can simple drag and move your `tabBarItem`. Where ever you want to set in `tabBarController`.